# hidden original files in j2me application

Tags: java-me, splash-screen

How to hide original files in j2me?ex. when u insert image for splash page,if user extract jar file and replace one image with your image and zip files,your application started by user's image!!

I found [BamFS](http://supremej2me.bambalam.se/guides/optimization-tools/bamfs/),but this not friendly.

Is there other answer?how to user byte stream to this?

Comment: BamFS is really simple, or you can create yourselves one